# Choosing a center for a Taylor polynomial of $f(x)=\tan(x)$ to best estimate $\tan(61°)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

So I've converted $61°$ to radians:

$$\frac{61\pi}{180^\circ} $$

Do I just look for a "clean" $x$ value nearby to this? Such as $\dfrac{π}{3}$ ?

Comment: That's how it's done.  This kind of exercise in calculus textbooks is silly, but few professors have give half a second's thought to the content of calculus courses since about 1970.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Okay thank you. Quick question on etiquette on this board: When I ask a small, specific question like this and have it answered, should I delete the question now?

Comment: There's no need for that.  Possibly someone will search for it a year from now and find this useful.